# Magento2 Missed Required Arguement httpContext in parent::__construct call

Tags: magento2

I have a custom Module with a file in `Block/Wishlist/prouctoptions.php`

The contents of the file are like this:

```
<?php
namespace Myweb\CustomArt\Block\Wishlist;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class ProductOptions extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info
{
    protected $_productloader;  
    public function __construct($_productloader, $context) {

        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);


    }
    /**
     * Retrieve form action
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIndexAction()
    {
            // companymodule is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

         return '/customart/index/index';
        // here controller_name is manage, action is contact
    }

}
```

While running the command `setup:di:compile` I am getting the error like:

```
Missed required argument httpContext in 
parent::__construct call. File:
 /public_html/app/code/Myweb/CustomArt/Block/Wishlist/Productoptions.php
Total Errors Count: 1
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: with a capital letter name file prouctoptions.php

Comment: ProductOptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Myweb\CustomArt\Block\Wishlist;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class ProductOptions extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info
{
    protected $_productloader;  

    public function __construct(
        $_productloader,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context,$httpContext);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve form action
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIndexAction()
    {
            // companymodule is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

         return '/customart/index/index';
        // here controller_name is manage, action is contact
    }

}
```

I don't understand why you added `$_productloader,` in your `__construct` method maybe you are calling it from XML.

Answer (score 1):

Please check __construct() function in your custom block whether you send all parameters for your parent __construct() function in file Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info